# Make Test fails

Tags: bug, ubuntu

I just tried to go through this yesterday on a new server build and am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

- Installed latest ubuntu on a VM.  Followed instructions here: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/getting-the-code to get the code.
- Then i ran ./eosio_build.sh which finished okay.
- Then i ran make install
- Then i ran a command to start mongodb as suggested by several
- Then when i run sudo make test i get the following:

Output:

```
Running tests...
Test project /home/matt/eos/build
      Start  1: test_cypher_suites
 1/33 Test  #1: test_cypher_suites .....................   Passed    0.02 sec
      Start  2: validate_simple.token_abi
 2/33 Test  #2: validate_simple.token_abi ..............   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start  3: validate_eosio.token_abi
 3/33 Test  #3: validate_eosio.token_abi ...............   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start  4: validate_eosio.msig_abi
 4/33 Test  #4: validate_eosio.msig_abi ................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start  5: validate_multi_index_test_abi
 5/33 Test  #5: validate_multi_index_test_abi ..........   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start  6: validate_eosio.system_abi
 6/33 Test  #6: validate_eosio.system_abi ..............   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start  7: validate_identity_abi
 7/33 Test  #7: validate_identity_abi ..................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start  8: validate_identity_test_abi
 8/33 Test  #8: validate_identity_test_abi .............   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start  9: validate_stltest_abi
 9/33 Test  #9: validate_stltest_abi ...................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 10: validate_exchange_abi
10/33 Test #10: validate_exchange_abi ..................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 11: validate_test.inline_abi
11/33 Test #11: validate_test.inline_abi ...............   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 12: validate_hello_abi
12/33 Test #12: validate_hello_abi .....................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 13: validate_asserter_abi
13/33 Test #13: validate_asserter_abi ..................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 14: validate_infinite_abi
14/33 Test #14: validate_infinite_abi ..................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 15: validate_proxy_abi
15/33 Test #15: validate_proxy_abi .....................   Passed    0.04 sec
      Start 16: validate_test_api_abi
16/33 Test #16: validate_test_api_abi ..................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 17: validate_test_api_mem_abi
17/33 Test #17: validate_test_api_mem_abi ..............   Passed    0.04 sec
      Start 18: validate_test_api_db_abi
18/33 Test #18: validate_test_api_db_abi ...............   Passed    0.05 sec
      Start 19: validate_test_api_multi_index_abi
19/33 Test #19: validate_test_api_multi_index_abi ......   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 20: validate_test_ram_limit_abi
20/33 Test #20: validate_test_ram_limit_abi ............   Passed    0.04 sec
      Start 21: validate_eosio.bios_abi
21/33 Test #21: validate_eosio.bios_abi ................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 22: validate_noop_abi
22/33 Test #22: validate_noop_abi ......................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 23: validate_dice_abi
23/33 Test #23: validate_dice_abi ......................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 24: validate_tic_tac_toe_abi
24/33 Test #24: validate_tic_tac_toe_abi ...............   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 25: validate_payloadless_abi
25/33 Test #25: validate_payloadless_abi ...............   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 26: unit_test_binaryen
26/33 Test #26: unit_test_binaryen .....................   Passed  100.62 sec
      Start 27: unit_test_wavm
27/33 Test #27: unit_test_wavm .........................   Passed  444.16 sec
      Start 28: plugin_test
28/33 Test #28: plugin_test ............................   Passed    0.02 sec
      Start 29: nodeos_run_test
29/33 Test #29: nodeos_run_test ........................***Failed    0.09 sec
      Start 30: nodeos_run_remote_test
30/33 Test #30: nodeos_run_remote_test .................***Failed    0.09 sec
      Start 31: distributed-transactions-test
31/33 Test #31: distributed-transactions-test ..........***Failed    0.09 sec
      Start 32: distributed-transactions-remote-test
32/33 Test #32: distributed-transactions-remote-test ...***Failed    0.09 sec
      Start 33: restart-scenarios-test_hard_replay
33/33 Test #33: restart-scenarios-test_hard_replay .....***Failed    0.09 sec

85% tests passed, 5 tests failed out of 33

Total Test time (real) = 546.08 sec

The following tests FAILED:
     29 - nodeos_run_test (Failed)
     30 - nodeos_run_remote_test (Failed)
     31 - distributed-transactions-test (Failed)
     32 - distributed-transactions-remote-test (Failed)
     33 - restart-scenarios-test_hard_replay (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
Makefile:119: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result on the new v1.2.0 code so I'll post another question.

Comment: I also have a new Ubuntu install (v18) and a fail at test "unit_test_wavm" #27. Any help out there?